# cakePHP - cant pull model association via belongsTo in second recursion

Tags: cakephp

[cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) I try to get a find('all'...) on a model with many associations in cakePHP 1.3, which does have the filter criteria for the query in the second level of the recursion within the schema. Simply, it looks like this and I want to filter for the UserId:

```
Delivery belongsTo Order, Order belongsTo User.
```

Here are the assocs:

> Order:
>   var $belongsTo = array(
>
> ```
>   'User' => array(
>       'className' => 'User',
>       'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
>       'conditions' => '',
>       'fields' => '',
>       'order' => ''
>   ),....
> ```
>
> Delivery:
>   var $belongsTo = array(
>
> ```
>    'Order' => array(
>        'className' => 'Order',
>        'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
>        'conditions' => '',
>        'fields' => '',
>        'order' => ''
>    ),...
> ```

The resulting error is:

> SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'User.id' in 'where clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

Here the full query, just for fun:

> SELECT `Delivery`.`id`, `Delivery`.`order_id`, `Delivery`.`delivery_address_id`, `Delivery`.`deliver_date`, `Delivery`.`created`, `Delivery`.`modified`, `Delivery`.`deliver_run`, `Delivery`.`product_mix_id1`, `Delivery`.`product_mix_id2`, `Delivery`.`product_mix_id3`, `Delivery`.`product_mix_id4`, `Delivery`.`assembled`, `Delivery`.`shipped`, `Delivery`.`rated`, `Delivery`.`price`, `Delivery`.`product_lines_id`, `Order`.`id`, `Order`.`user_id`, `Order`.`product_lines_id`, `Order`.`order_date`, `Order`.`deliver_monday`, `Order`.`deliver_tuesday`, `Order`.`deliver_wednessday`, `Order`.`deliver_thursday`, `Order`.`deliver_friday`, `Order`.`deliver_saturday`, `Order`.`delivery_address_id`, `Order`.`payment_delay`, `Order`.`active`, `Order`.`cancle_date`, `Order`.`replaced_order_id`, `Order`.`created`, `Order`.`modified`, `DeliveryAddress`.`id`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_company`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_title`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_first_name`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_last_name`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_street`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_house_nr`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_postal_code`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_town`, `DeliveryAddress`.`delivery_country`, `DeliveryAddress`.`created`, `DeliveryAddress`.`deleted`, `DeliveryAddress`.`modified`, `ProductLine`.`id`, `ProductLine`.`name`, `ProductLine`.`description`, `ProductMix1`.`id`, `ProductMix1`.`name`, `ProductMix1`.`description`, `ProductMix1`.`image_small_path`, `ProductMix1`.`image_normal_path`, `ProductMix1`.`product_categories_id`, `ProductMix1`.`depricated`, `ProductMix1`.`created`, `ProductMix1`.`modified`, `ProductMix2`.`id`, `ProductMix2`.`name`, `ProductMix2`.`description`, `ProductMix2`.`image_small_path`, `ProductMix2`.`image_normal_path`, `ProductMix2`.`product_categories_id`, `ProductMix2`.`depricated`, `ProductMix2`.`created`, `ProductMix2`.`modified`, `ProductMix3`.`id`, `ProductMix3`.`name`, `ProductMix3`.`description`, `ProductMix3`.`image_small_path`, `ProductMix3`.`image_normal_path`, `ProductMix3`.`product_categories_id`, `ProductMix3`.`depricated`, `ProductMix3`.`created`, `ProductMix3`.`modified`, `ProductMix4`.`id`, `ProductMix4`.`name`, `ProductMix4`.`description`, `ProductMix4`.`image_small_path`, `ProductMix4`.`image_normal_path`, `ProductMix4`.`product_categories_id`, `ProductMix4`.`depricated`, `ProductMix4`.`created`, `ProductMix4`.`modified` FROM `deliveries` AS `Delivery` LEFT JOIN `orders` AS `Order` ON (`Delivery`.`order_id` = `Order`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `delivery_addresses` AS `DeliveryAddress` ON (`Delivery`.`delivery_address_id` = `DeliveryAddress`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `product_lines` AS `ProductLine` ON (`Delivery`.`product_lines_id` = `ProductLine`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `product_mixes` AS `ProductMix1` ON (`Delivery`.`product_mix_id1` = `ProductMix1`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `product_mixes` AS `ProductMix2` ON (`Delivery`.`product_mix_id2` = `ProductMix2`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `product_mixes` AS `ProductMix3` ON (`Delivery`.`product_mix_id3` = `ProductMix3`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `product_mixes` AS `ProductMix4` ON (`Delivery`.`product_mix_id4` = `ProductMix4`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`id` = 1

Does anyone know why cake does not pull the second level, in this case the User model, when even recursive is set to 5?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the model cache(s)?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: It just occurred to me that in your case you don't need 2nd level `JOIN` actually, as you can filter by `Order.user_id` (instead of `User.id`)! Do you see my point?

So probably you don't need solution below.

---

As far as I know, Cake never does 2nd level `JOIN` itself, so for filtering (conditions) on 2nd level (and deeper) I use [`joins`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables).

For your example:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'orders',
        'alias' => 'Order',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Order.id = Delivery.order_id',
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'alias' => 'User',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id = Order.user_id',
            'User.some_field' => $someFilteringValue
        )
    )
);
$result = $this->Delivery->find('all', $options);
```